# separate python script cannot find self-defined module inside Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my Django app folder structure

```
|-----tt
|      |--settings.py
|
|-----warehouse
|       |--models.py
|       |--__init__.py
|
|-----dashboard
|       |--email_excel_reports.py
|
```

Inside my `email_excel_reports.py`

```
# for ORM query
from warehouse.models import EntryFormLineItem
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.utils import timezone


line_items = EntryFormLineItem.objects.filter(approved_by__isnull=False, ...
```

I got this error when I run `python email_excel_reports.py` inside `dashboard`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/dashboard/email_excel_reports.py", line 11, in <module>
    from warehouse.models import EntryFormLineItem
ImportError: No module named 'warehouse'
```

**Bear in mind that when I run the `python email_excel_reports.py` I was running gunicorn with nginx, so the `django` app is running successfully.**

The `__init__.py` inside `warehouse`

```
default_app_config = 'warehouse.apps.WarehouseConfig'
```

When I run `python manage.py shell` and then type the same lines of code, there was no problem running the code.

How do I get over the error?

**RE-OPEN -- WHY?**

Simply because the fix was to have `python manage.py shell <` placed in front of the python script file and this fix was not available in the supposedly duplicated question's answers.

Comment: is there a `__init__.py` file in your `warehouse` directory?

Comment: yes and I have just added the contents into the question

Comment: You need to set up django environment, when you want to run this script in command line.

Comment: I am already running gunicorn and nginx when I run the python script. And I read the question about using django for CLI tool. So I need to add `# Setup django
    import django
    django.setup()` inside manage.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the need to include the django modules, the better way to run this is

`python manage.py shell < dashboard/email_excel_reports.py`

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem by putting the standalone Python file into the same directory as `manage.py`. (Since it's in the project root directory, all the modules are available beneath it).